# How games which are made of Unity can integrate Immersive Ads?

Tags: unity

As we are going into 2024, I'm seeing a lot of mentions regarding immersive ads. I'm just curious to know how I can implement this in my unity game.

Comment: How do you define what you consider to be an "immersive ad"? What are the main characteristics you want to achieve?

Comment: By immersive I want to say native to the gameplay. So that it can blend with the game.

Comment: It sounds then like the answer would depend on the particulars of your game's gameplay, and there wouldn't be a general-purpose recipe or universal set of steps that would apply to every game. Want to try to **edit your question** to tell us more about your game, how you want ads to appear in that game, and what step in the process you need help with?